# How to convert PyFrameObject to PyObject

Tags: python, c, cython, python-extensions, python-embedding

Maybe I'm missing something, but here is a problem:

I'm tracing python code by C extensions and my trace function got PyFrameObject* frame. Now I want to process the frame by Python code(embedded or converted to C by Cython) but it deals with PyObject*.

How do I convert PyFrameObject* to PyObject*? I don't find appropriate convertion funciton in frameobject.h.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a cast:

```
PyObject *myObject = (PyObject *)myFrameObject
```

This is standard for the Python C API; everything that "inherits" from `PyObject` has a `PyObject_VAR_HEAD` at the top of the object so a pointer to the object is convertible to a pointer to `PyObject`.